# Selective Find & Replace to pretty up my C code in Eclipse or Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, eclipse, find-and-replace

I am working on a old C code which have debug statments like this:

```
debug(1, "SomeDebugStmt %s %d", someString, someNumber);
...
debug(2, "another SomeDebugStmt number 2 %s %d", anotherString, anotherNumber);
```

There are hundreds of such debug statements in this C file.

How could I change such debug statements to this format:

```
debug(1, "%s--[%d] SomeDebugStmt %s %d", fname, line, someSTring, someNumber);
...
debug(2, "%s--[%d] another SomeDebugStmt number 2 %s %d", fname, line, someSTring, anotherString, anotherNumber);
```

I was thinking find & replace using regex might be able to do this but I am not sure if it can somehow remember to replace exact string from the original while adding some extra string values. I have option to use Eclispe or Notepad++. Any hints/pointers appriciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with notepad++ with following RegExp for "Find what:"

```
debug\(([0-9]+,) "
```

and replace with

```
debug(\1 "%s--[%d] "
```

Explanation of the regexp

```
debug         ; find the text "debug"
\(            ; followed by a opening parenthesis,
              ; parentheses have a special meaning in regexp, 
              ; so they must be escaped with a backslash
(             ; followed by the first subpattern, that will go in backreference \1
  [0-9]+      ; one or more digits
  ,           ; followed by a comma
)             ; end of the subpattern
 "            ; followed by a blank and a double quote
```

We replace this with

```
debug(        ; exact this text
\1            ; followed by the content of the first subpattern
 "            ; the blank and the double quote
%s--[%d] "   ; and the text you want to insert in those lines
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that clean explanation. I had to do some tweaks but your explanation did help me and saved tons of time. ThankQ!! <br/>
Find:
debug\(([0-9]+, ?)"([a-zA-Z0-9 :%_=!,.\/\->\(\)\[\]\*]+)"( ?,?) <br/>
Replace:
debug\(\1"%s\[%d\]: \2", fname, line\3